# Map elements from "stream in stream" to Set

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm new to Java streams.

I have an Array of n classes.

The classes have several fields with a particular annotation (SomeAnnotationClass.class)

I'm trying to get a Set of all the fields annotations values which are annotated with this particular annotation. If the field does not have the annotation I want the name of the field.

So i tried something like this:

```
     Stream.of(clazzes).map( c ->
        Stream.of((c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(
                field ->
                    Optional.ofNullable(
                        field.getDeclaredAnnotation(SomeAnnotationClass.class).value())
                        .orElse(field.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

2 issues with this:

1. I get a Set<Set> instead of Set due to collecting 2 times.
2. I get a Nullpointer if the annotation is not present but SomeAnnotationClass.class.value() is called

Can I achieve this elegantly with streams?

Comment: Are you looking for (1) [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), and (2) [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)?

Comment: `Stream.of(clazzes).flatMap(c->c.getDeclaredFields().stream()).map(Optional.ofNullable(
                        field.getDeclaredAnnotation(SomeAnnotationClass.class)).map(a->a.value())
                        .orElse(field.getName()))).collect(Collectors.toSet())` maybe?

Comment: @dan1st, you should have posted it as an answer, it would be more readable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of sets should be flattened:

```java
// in Main.java
public static Set<String> getValuesOrNames(Class ... clazzes) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazzes)  // convert array to Stream<Class>
                 .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields())) // convert array of fields Stream<Field>
                 .map(field -> Optional.ofNullable(field.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotationClass.class))
                        .map(SomeAnnotationClass::value) // assuming SomeAnnotationClass has value method
                        .orElse(field.getName())
                 )
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Test

```java
// annotation class
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotationClass {
    String value() default "";
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import lombok.Data;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getValuesOrNames(Something.class, Main.class));
    }

    @Data
    public static class Something {
        @SomeAnnotationClass(value = "String foo")
        private String foo;

        @SomeAnnotationClass
        private String emptyFoo;

        private String bar;

        @SomeAnnotationClass(value = "int id")
        private int id;
    }
}
```

Output

```
[, String foo, bar, int id]
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @WJS right, one dangling `)`. `))` should be `)`

Comment: @WJS, it compiles now

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Andy Turner, you can use to `flatMap` to map multiple streams into single stream and to avoid `NPE` check the annotation before accessing `value()`

```
Set<String> value = clazzes.stream().map(c -> Stream.of((c.getDeclaredFields()))
               .map(field -> Optional.ofNullable(
                           field.getDeclaredAnnotation(SomeAnnotationClass.class)).map(SomeAnnotationClass::value).orElseGet(field::getName)).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
               .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package io.falcon.instagram.indexer.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class<?>> classes = List.of(Test.class);
        
        Class<Enumerated> someAnnotationClass = Enumerated.class;
        
        Set<String> fieldNames = 
                classes.stream()
                .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields().clone())) // because getDeclaredFields returns array type
                .map((Field field) -> Optional.ofNullable(field.getDeclaredAnnotation(someAnnotationClass)).map(a -> field.getName()))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
        System.out.println(fieldNames);
    }



    public static class Test {
        @Id
        private final String id;
        @Id
        @Enumerated
        private final String field;
        @Enumerated
        private final String another;
        @Enumerated
        private final String theGame;

        public Test(String id, String field, String another, String theGame) {
            this.id = id;
            this.field = field;
            this.another = another;
            this.theGame = theGame;
        }
    }
}
```